# invisible border not working correctly

Tags: html, css, border

i am making a website but when i want to make a border transparent to "subtract" it from a div, it is not working. can anyone tell me whats going on and how i could fix this? also when i zoom in the borders grow but the rest doenst, can someone tell me a fix for that too?
here's the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title> Homepagina </title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css">
    <meta charset="utf-8">

    <!--Dit laadt het Raleway lettertype: -->
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:200,300' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

    <!--Dit laadt jQuery: -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"> </script>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.6/jquery-ui.min.js"> </script>
</head>




<body>

    <div class="topBar">
        hoi 
    </div>

    <div class="jumbotron">
        <div class="overMij">

        </div>

        <div class="hobbies">

        </div>

        <div class="muziek">

        </div>

        <div class="informatica">

        </div>
    </div>

</body>
```

```
html, body { 
    margin: 0;  
    width: 100%; 
    height: 100%;
    background-image: url(background.jpg)
}

.topBar {
    height: 10%;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: blue;

}

.jumbotron {
    height: 90%;
    width: 100%;
}

.overMij {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; 
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;    
    background-color: green;
    background-size: 100%;
    width: 60%;
    height: 50%;
    float: left;
    border-radius: 50px;
    border: solid white 25px;
}

.hobbies {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; 
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    background-color: green;
    background-size: 100%;
    width: 40%;
    height: 50%;
    float: right;
    border-radius: 50px;
    border: solid white 25px;
}

.muziek {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; 
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    background-color: green;
    background-size: 100%;
    width: 40%;
    height: 50%;
    float: left;
    border-radius: 50px;
    border: solid white 25px;
}

.informatica {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; 
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    background-color: green;
    background-size: 100%;
    width: 60%;
    height: 50%;
    float: right;
    border-radius: 50px;
    border: solid white 25px;
}
```

Comment: Are you wanting there to not be a border?

Comment: @kfreeman04208 i want the background color to not be the whole height and width of the div, so i tried padding and margin but it was way difficult with 60 and 40% so i tried border which seems to work, but i wantr the border to be transparent and to show the background, if you get what i mean

Comment: which bordder? You've got 4 in there.

Comment: @Candy_In_Mah_Van What is the purpose of borders? Do you want to add space between `divs`?

Comment: @alirezasafian yes, exactly that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `margin` instead of `transparent` border.

I optimize your css. You can check this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alireza_safian/phg7w9u6/)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `background-clip` for this:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background: #bada55;
}

div {
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  margin: 25px auto;
  border:2px solid grey;
  padding:10px;
  background: #f00;
  background-clip: content-box;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

[**Background-clip @ MDN**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/background-clip)

[**Support @ CanIUse.com**](http://caniuse.com/#search=background-clip)

Comment: Perhaps you could make a demo of the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your border property see if its what you want. I found a white.

```
border: 25px solid rgba(255,255,255, 1);
```

Comment: also doesnt work, it makes the border darker green instead of showing the background

Answer (score 0):

Margins is definitely something you need to do. Boarders are always a part of the divs. You shouldn't be using them to separate divs. Below is the updated CSS and Codepen for you:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/PPRBMe

```
.overMij {  
    background-color: black;
    background-size: 100%;
    width: 58%;
    height: 48%;
    float: left;
    border-radius: 50px;
    margin: 1%
}

.hobbies {
    background-color: grey;
    background-size: 100%;
    width: 38%;
    height: 48%;
    float: right;
    border-radius: 50px;
    margin: 1%;
}

.muziek {
    background-color: purple;
    background-size: 100%;
    width: 38%;
    height: 38%;
    float: left;
    border-radius: 50px;
    margin: 1%;
}

.informatica {
    background-color: green;
    background-size: 100%;
    width: 58%;
    height: 38%;
   float: left;
    border-radius: 50px;
    margin: 1%;
}
```